# ASTParser dependencies

Tags: java, parsing, dependencies, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to learn ASTParser with the help of [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/) tutorial. When I compile the first slice of code:

`ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS2);
parser.setSource("".toCharArray());
CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); 
unit.recordModifications();
AST ast = unit.getAST();`

I get this error:

> Source non found. The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Plug-in Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/), you should include these jar files:

- org.eclipse.core.contenttype.jar
- org.eclipse.core.jobs.jar
- org.eclipse.core.resources.jar
- org.eclipse.core.runtime.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.common.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.jar
- org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar
- org.eclipse.osgi.jar

Comment: Dang - needed this yesterday and figured it out myself the hard way!